# Correlating data from two tables in Oracle using a third which maps them together

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to JOIN/UNION/whatever data from two tables based on a third which maps them together. Here is the idea:

Table USERS contains user ID, username, some other data.
Table GROUPS contains group ID, group name, some other data.

Table USERGROUPMAP contains a bunch of user IDs and group IDs mapped together which correspond to IDs in USERS and GROUPS. Each user can be in multiple groups, each group can have multiple users.

I have always done this by storing objects or CSV data in a single field, e.g. making a column in groups called MEMBERS and storing id1,id2,id3...but this is what I was presented with.

I can't change the schema...I know this has something to do with JOINs or UNIONs or something but my SQL is very rusty, so can anyone help out here?

My maybe semi-correct idea -

```
SELECT USERS.uid, 
       GROUPS.gid, 
       USERGROUPMAP.uid, 
       USERGROUPMAP.gid 
  FROM USERS, 
       GROUPS, 
       USERGROUPMAP 
  JOIN ON ((USERS.uid = USERGROUPMAP.uid) AND (GROUPS.gid = USERGROUPMAP.gid))
```

Any tips? :( .. Thanks guys.

**Edit, expected IO**

USERS table contains a bunch of UIDs ... 1,2,3,4,5, so on
GROUPS table contains a bunch of GIDs, 1000,1001,1002 and so on

USERGROUPMAP contains tuples corresponding to which users are in which groups, eg  (1,1002) (2,1000) (5,1003) (5,1000)

I am trying to get a list of groups a user is in, so for this example I want to get two rows of 5,1003 and 5,1000 ... make sense?

Comment: I understand your tables and structure but I am not sure what kind of output you are looking for here. Can you provide a scenario and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.userID, a.name, b.groupName
from USERS a, GROUPS b, USERGROUPMAP c
where c.userID = a.userID and 
b.groupID = c.groupID and
c.userID = <searchID>
```

The userID you want to search is the searchID in the query. You can replace userID with groupID if you are listing users for a group.

Comment: I was actually under the impression that implicit joins with WHERE like this are really slow...or at least used to be (my last oracle foray was...8?) Is this reasonably fast?

Comment: With multiple tables, you can not avoid it. This is the fastest way. You can try running various types of queries but unless your table is really huge, you wont see any noticeable difference.

Comment: Unless you're using a really old version of Oracle, both styles should have the same performance.

Comment: Oh yeah, the query optimizer should be able to take over and find the best execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no duplicates in USERS nor GROUPS, it's a simple join between the three tables:

```
SELECT
  USERS.FIELD1,
  USERS.FIELD2,
  -- ...
  USERS.FIELDN,
  GROUPS.FIELD1,
  GROUPS.FIELD2,
  -- ...
  GROUPS.FIELDN
FROM USERS
JOIN USERGROUPMAP ON USERS.UID = USERGROUPMAP.UID
JOIN GROUPS ON USERGROUPMAP.GID = GROUPS.GID
```

Comment: This is also correct I guess, though I can't accept more than one answer. :(